# Read specific amount of characters in the middle of a string (C)

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a maximum of 15 characters with sscanf. Everything I need to read is between `'` and `'`. I still need to read other things afterwards.

```
char event_str[16];
char day_str[10];
char time_start_str[6];
char time_end_str[6];
sscanf(user_input + 11, " %[^']' %s %s %s", event_str, day_str, time_start_str, time_end_str);
```

A potential user_input could be:

```
add event 'Trip to Ikea with mom' monday 15:00 20:00
```

The first character I read is the T in trip; is it possible to only read the next 15 characters, and then go on and read the rest?

Comment: Try `" %15[^'\n]"` to read the section with max 15 characters. And then `" %*[^'\n]'"` to read and discard the rest of the quoted section.

Comment: Or find the two `'` enclosing characters with `strchr()` and extract the relevant sections using that.

Comment: Then you'll want to escape \' so you can encode "don't"; it gets complicated very fast. So much easier to use a lexer, which was designed specifically for this type of input.